# Does $ 1 + 1/2 - 1/3 + 1/4 +1/5 - 1/6 + 1/7 + 1/8 - 1/9 + ...$ converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Does $ 1 + 1/2 - 1/3 + 1/4 +1/5 - 1/6 + 1/7 + 1/8 - 1/9 + ...$ converge?

I know that $(a_n)= 1/n$ diverges, and $(a_n)= (-1)^n (1/n)$, converges, but given this pattern of a negative number every third element, I am unsure how to determine if this converges.

I tried to use the comparison test, but could not find sequences to compare it to, and the alternating series test doesn't seem to work, because every other is not negative.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Conditional_convergence

Comment: No, you know $\sum 1/n$ diverges and $\sum (-1)^n/n$ converges.

Comment: Note the (classical) names for these two series: "harmonic series" and "alternating harmonic series".

Answer (score 5):

Let $s_n$ be the $n$th partial sum of the series. If the series converges, then the sequence $\{s_n\}$ is bounded.

However, observe that $s_4>1+\frac{1}{4}$, $s_7> 1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{7}$, and in general
$$ s_{3m+1}>\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{1}{3k+1} $$
Since $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3k+1}$ diverges, this shows that the sequence $\{s_n\}$ is not bounded, so the series diverges.

Comment: Why is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3k+1}$ diverging?

Comment: Is this because $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3(k+1)}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{k+1}<\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3k+1}$ where the former is a scalar multiple of harmonic series, which is unbounded. By comparison test, the original series, therefore, diverges?

Comment: @zony_miu Yes, that's right

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $1 + 1/2 - 1/3 > 1$, $1/4 + 1/5 - 1/6 > 1/4$, $1/7 + 1/8 - 1/9 > 1/7$, ...